# Is it possible to redirect a process's system calls to a different dynamic library?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, system-calls

I have an application that occasionally stores information to a file. For a particular reason, I find it necessary to have the information stored in a database system like MySQL. So is it possible for me to safely hijack the `read` and `write` system calls (in Ubuntu) produced by the application and cause it to store the information to a MySQL database instead of letting the application write to the file system?

Let `A` be the application.

`A -> calls:read   ->  reads-from-file-system`

`A -> calls:write  ->  writes-to-file-system`

This is how the application originally functions. Is it possible to write a program (without messing with the Kernel-mode if possible) and implement two functions `mysql_wrapped_read` and `mysql_wrapped_write`, which respectively substitutes the original `read` and `write` function in the application?

So now, the scenario becomes:

`A -> calls:mysql_wrapped_read   ->  reads-from-mysql-database`

`A -> calls:mysql_wrapped_write  ->  writes-to-mysql-database`

Can you please tell me if this is possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Assuming its not a statically linked program, you could write a `.so` "shim" and use `LD_PRELOAD`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helped! This was exactly what I was looking for!